# bash dir string construction from command in one line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command

```
dir=$(pwd; echo '/hi/'; date "+%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")

echo $dir
```

gives

```
/some/path/hear /hi/ 2014_11_30-12_40_17
```

Why are there spaces ?
how to make this path in one line with out spaces ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way, I think:

```
dir="$(pwd)/hi/$(date '+%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S')"
```

the `$()` expressions work just like normal variables in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed.

```
$ dir=$(pwd; echo '/hi/'; date "+%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")
$ dir=$(sed 's/ //g' <<< $dir)
$ echo $dir
/home/path/hi/2014_11_30-18_21_09
```

Answer (score 1):

This still works as well:

```
$ dir=`pwd`/hi/$(date '+%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S')
$ echo $dir
/home/oracle/hi/2014_11_30-14_18_30
$
```

Funny there are so many ways of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf`.

```
$ printf '%s/hi/%s\n' "$(pwd)" "$(date "+%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")"
/home/path/hi/2014_11_30-07_53_05
```